# Unable to load "wpColorPicker" on theme customize page

Tags: widgets, javascript

Whether I'm using a Wordpress default theme or a custom one, I see the JS error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpColorPicker'` when I click "Customize" on the theme.  I've also noticed that on the widgets page nothing is draggable.  I believe these issues may be related as I just moved this site to a new server.  I've verified all files are  chmod `755`.  I'm a bit unfamiliar with the inner workings of Wordpress.  Is there a debug mode or something I can enable?

I recognize with the widgets I can enable accessibility mode, but the bigger issue there is I can't Customize my theme due to the JS error.

*I've verified that this error persists when all plugins are disabled*

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to install & activate the "Use Google Libraries" plugin which loads resources from Google's CDN.  I'm unsure why this is a fix, but it worked.

Comment: Not sure why? "Use Google Libraries"??????? Signals show something is wrong. Stop using whatever and find a better solution.

Comment: With no custom code or plugins, you will never see this error on WordPress.

Comment: *should never* what is you hosting setup with the naked WP setup? JavaScript errors like this are signs of security issues.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you enqueue wpColorPicker on the page
`wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );`
 and that error sounds like you are not calling the function on a jQuery object? Should have something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.color-picker').wpColorPicker();
});
```

Also make sure you are calling it on an input like so:

```
<input type="text" value="#e55d22" class="color-picker" />
```

Comment: Thanks - but I wasn't doing any custom development, just a wordpress user.

Comment: oh ok, well you could use firebug or a similar program to see where the error is coming from, is this a new theme or installation of WP>